# MySQL: sum of two columns

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a column within a MySQL structure that automatically sums two other columns?

So if I have a table called `TABLE`:

```
Column A, Column B, and Column C.
```

I would want `Column C` to automatically sum `Column A` and `Column B`.

Is that possible?

If A changes, C changes.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible with a View or a trigger. The View is the better solution in most cases.

**View:**

Your table `TABLE` would have only the columns `A` and `B`.
The view would then look something like this:

```
create or replace view V_TABLE as
select A, B, A + B as C
from TABLE;
```

If you need to query TABLE you use the view instead of the table itself. Each query will than return the correct C.

**Trigger:**

Your table `TABLE` would have all three columns `A`, `B` and `C`.
You would create a trigger on `A` and on `B` that update `C` as soon as `A` or `B` changes.

This answer assumes that in your case it is not feasible to calculate the value directly in your application.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do is to calculate the records in your application level before inserting it on the database.

Comment: @AndrásOttó I partly agree with you. What if the value was edited manually or by some script

Comment: I am trying to sort an array by the difference of two fields.  So if I was able to have a field that did that, I would be able to just sort by that field.  Instead, i'd have to sort on the application level which I can't seem to figure out how to sort a multidimensional array.

Comment: @DanielFein: In that case a view would be more appropriate as this information is nothing that really needs to be stored.